# Is serial voting detection script run for meta-sites, too?

Tags: support, serial-voting, per-site-meta

I have noticed on one meta site a bunch of nice answer badges awarded to the same user more-or-less around the same time. This can be caused by something else, but nevertheless, it made me think whether serial up/down-votes occur at meta sites, too, and whether they are also reversed there. (It is difficult to say, since reputation breakdown is not shown on meta, so I do not know whether some posts of mine have been upvoted and whether upvotes have been reversed.)

> Is serial voting detected (and reversed) on per-site-metas, too?

Comment: I'm puzzled by the "reputation breakdown is not shown on meta" claim, esp. in regard to ones own posts.  Clicking on my account's Reputation link gives the options to view by post, time, or graph.  I'm not sure if the post and time options are really different (they appear alike on my account), and perhaps you have in mind some other feature.

Comment: @hardmath When I look at my [profile page on a per-site-meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/8297/martin-sleziak) (or at [your profile page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/3111/hardmath)) I do not see there any reputation tab.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at Meta.SO, where one actually accrues reputation (unlike the per-site-meta's).  I see your point now.

Comment: Just in case someone is curious, the details about what made me ask about this can be found [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14739043#14739043). It seems that some upvotes have been reversed. (Some of the answers that have received nice answer badge around the same time are back to score 9. It is not probable, considering the number of answers, that it was just a coincidence.)

Comment: Why did you accept a link only answer, with wrong assumption? Shog could have meant "all main sites", he never mentioned meta sites.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the serial voting detection script runs on all sites.

As Shog said the same here: [Do serial voting detection scripts really work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224874/244382)

Comment: The only mention of Meta in Shog's answer is: *I've found that I tend to collect a lot of upvotes on days when I'm particularly visible: on Stack Overflow that tends to mean a featured meta post,* That doesn't seem to indicate that the script actually runs on Meta; it seems to just be something that might cause people to serially upvote him, which could theoretically be on main sites. So while your answer might be correct, I don't think your source necessarily demonstrates your point.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it does run on child metas and here on Meta SE, the same as any site.

Here is the most conclusive post (and also a request for this to be changed): [The vote fraud script breaks legitimate polling questions - A serial downvoter's lament](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150180/323179). There, apparently-notorious serial-meta-serial-voter yannis admits to downvoting answers on poll questions to later see that the votes were reversed.

Be careful making polls! Try to avoid having too many default options posted by the same person, or let the community post their own answers based on what they believe. Or maybe just stop posting stuff so terrible that everyone needs to serial downvote it :)