# Serial vote reversal strangeness? Bug or feature?

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, serial-voting

Something strange has been happening on meta.SciFi recently...

[Someone started a poll to see if people wanted to change the name of the main chat room.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/primary-chatroom-name-polling)

But at least twice now, I've voted on the question and on several of the answers, only to have those votes apparently disappear.

[The leading speculation is that it's due to the serial vote reversal script:](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/bug-votes-not-being-recorded) since the question and most of the answers were posted by the same person, if you disagree with the idea of changing the name AND don't like many of the suggested new names, you're casting a lot of votes against the OP.

This raises a few questions:

1. Since this is a meta site, there's no reputation graph, so can you even tell if your votes are being reversed?
2. Since voting on meta doesn't cost points, should serial votes be reversed on a meta site?
3. If this is an artifact of serial vote reversal, how should a poll like this be conducted?  (I'm less interested in this.)

Comment: I think I ran into this too, when [math.se] was discussing potential names for the site blog. Someone posted a ton of lousy suggestions, I downvoted all of them, and later found the votes reversed. Suggestion for 3: institute a rule that only upvotes count on polls, and people should upvote the name they prefer most. If they upvote too many, it simply means they don't know what name they want.

Comment: Think I've seen the same on Aera 51, recently someone made a proposal and all the sample questions were at about -5. I only downvoted the two worst ones and the next day noticed only my votes had seemed to stick.

Comment: Related: [The vote fraud script breaks legitimate polling questions - A serial downvoter's lament](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150180/the-vote-fraud-script-breaks-legitimate-polling-questions-a-serial-downvoters)

Comment: Somewhat related: [Is serial voting detection script run for meta-sites, too?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228609)